# Where are you Generic Web Templates Connector

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

Does anyone know where I can get hold of the "Generic Web Templates Connector" for mylyn to use with a recent version of Eclipse (Kepler)? There are quite a few how-to pages ([1](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui/Mylyn/User_Guide/Task-Repository-Connectors.html), [2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Generic_Web_Templates_Connector), ...) pointing to [the main mylyn download page](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) saying to get it from the *incubator update site*. However, there is no sign of the incubator site on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn) has a direct link to the *incubator update site* for Mylyn 3.8.

The address is: http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.8

Presumably with Mylyn 3.11 being the latest release means that the *incubator update site* to use with an up-to-date Mylyn is: http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.11.

Yep that works... and the "Generic Web Templates Connector" can be found there.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work;  it's impressive how many dead links you will find about this plugin; I'm starting to think that mylyn was a great idea which never really took off :-(